# Prototype не наследует свойства объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп

Есть вот такой код

```
window.Market.VideoLiner = function(place, options=null) {
    if (!(place instanceof window.jQuery) || !place.length) {
      throw new window.Error('place is not jQuery object.')
    }
    this.options = Object.assign(window.Market.VideoLiner.options, options||{})
    this.place = place
    this.line = place.children(this.options.line_selector)
    this.next_selector = this.options.next_selector
    this.prev_selector = this.options.prev_selector
    this.next = $(this.next_selector)
    this.prev = $(this.prev_selector)
    this.position = 0
    return this
  }
```

Но, когда созадю прототип, просто не видит его.

если в созданный прототип записать

```
var p = 545
console.log('p',p)
```

тупо не выводит, что не так? Я признаться не могу понять.

```
  window.Market.VideoLiner.prototype.activate = function() {
    this.activate_ui()
  }
  window.Market.VideoLiner.options = {
    listener_selector: 'body',
    next_selector: '.liner-next',
    prev_selector: '.liner-prev',
    main_page_selector : '#wrapper #top .rows',
    line_selector: '.liner-line',
    division_selector: 'div.box.blocks',
    division_width: 310,
    window_division: 1,
    division_step: 1
  }
  window.Market.VideoLiner.activate = function(){
    var main_page = $(window.Market.VideoLiner.options.main_page_selector)
    if (!main_page.length == true) {
      return null
    }
    var dom = main_page.find('.boxs .box-liner .liner')
    new window.Market.VideoLiner($(dom))
  }
```

Comment: я не понял: что и где не видит? и что не выводится? _если записать туда_ - туда это куда?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы у объекта были прототипы, я их и создаю, но они не отображаются, в данном случае, this - не передается. и далее по цепочке this.activate_ui() - не подключается

Comment: В какой строке кода ты обращаешься к свойству из прототипа? сделай [mcve]. А приведенном коде не используется ничего из прототипа.

Comment: window.Market.VideoLiner.prototype.activate = function() {
    this.activate_ui()
  } Разве нет?Код, к сожалению, огромный, и сюда его выложить не получится

Comment: Нет, в этом месте ты просто добавляешь свойство в прототип, но в коде ты его нигде не вызываешь. По крайней мере в приведенном коде.

Comment: Вот собственно и ответ на вопрос мой, я забыл его вызвать. var a = new window.Market.VideoLiner($(dom)); a.activate(). Благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка глупая и невнимательная.Как и сказал `Grundy`,надо было вызвать этот объект, после уже добавлять свойства.

```
var a = new window.Market.VideoLiner($(dom)); 
a.activate()
```

Либо просто

```
new window.Market.VideoLiner($(dom)).activate();
```